# If $z=\frac{(\sqrt 3 - i)^{99}}{(1-i)^{101}}$, then the value of $\left(|z|\right)^{\frac{2}{97}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Answer given below. This question has been posted for a friend. Since it’s only adding information to the site and nothing else, I don’t think it should be taken down just for being irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|z|=\left[\frac{2^{99}}{\sqrt 2^{101}}\right]$$
$$=2^{\frac{97}{2}}$$
Then the value of expression asked is 
$$=\left(2^{\frac{97}{2}}\right)^{\frac{2}{97}}$$
$$=2$$